# Crank Nicolson, Equation format (Partial Different Equation)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to compare problems, but the format of the equation is stumping me.
[image]

In comparison to 
[image]

How do I formulate the Crank Nicolson with the first equation to the format of the second equation, or are they the same?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the mesh is exactly the same, 3 inner grid lines where you have to compute the first value. The coefficients change of course.

Comment: Both equations are of the form $u_t=cu_xx+f(x)$ and get discretized as $\frac{u^{n+1}_j-u^n_j}{Δt}=\frac{c}2\frac{(Δ_x^2u)^{n+1}_j+(Δ_x^2u)^n_j}{Δx^2}+f(x_j).$$

Comment: Thanks, that really pinned the nail, stay safe!